# Custom Question List screws up some tags

Tags: bug, question-lists

The Custom Question List I opted in seems to screw up some tags if searching for questions with "my watched tags". E.g. the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag becomes a [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag, that I actually ignore. The [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and [c++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) tags get stripped off the "c++" part and are just numbers [11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/11) and [14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/14). Maybe this also happens for other tags with special characters.

[image: Image showing the bug]

Comment: You'd think [tag:c++] and [tag:c#] test cases are included by default now whenever the devs do something tag-related.

Comment: Bugs with the custom question list need to be reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313940/388562). For this specific bug I suggest you look at [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314162/388562) that has already been posted.

Comment: I would really love to have cross-site duplicates for cases like this...

Comment: There's a joke about undefined behavior in here, somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not reproducing this with c / c++11 / c++14 despite toggling states of watching, unlatching, ignoring, etc. All characters allowed in tags (from what I can see) function normally (repeated with all sharps and pluses and whatnots):

[image: Screenshot of tag overlay dialog]

I also made sure that we weren't inadvertently borking this in the URLs themselves. I can't seem to reproduce this.

What are you doing that I'm not doing? I get this overwhelming sensation that I might be dense here, but I can't see where.

Comment: This seems to be happening when you add a tag in the filter part of the new custom question thingy. For the freehand circle version see [the top image in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314162/388562). Weirdly it doesn't happen when you **only** use the c++ tag for example.